# parse query doesn't return results

Tags: parse-platform

i have defined a parse cloud code call getChat (as below), but when i run it, it doesn't return any results

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getChat", function(request, response) {
  var allchat = [];
  var query = new Parse.Query("chat");
  query.find().then(function(results) {
    console.error("test"); //nothing in console
    console.error(results.length); //nothing in console
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
      for(var iii = 0; iii<results[i].get("limitleft").length; iii+=2){
        if(results[i].get("limitleft")[iii] == request.params.user){
          allchat.push(results[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  response.success(allchat);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Query.find() returns a Promise. ".then" attaches a callback function to that promise. When the Find completes, it executes the callback. However, you called response.success() right after you initiated the Find. The results have not been delivered yet. Calling response.success() effectively cancels the find because getChat has been completed by calling response.success().

Put the call to response.success() inside the block!

-Bob

Comment: so that code run it on background and then run the next code?

Comment: When the function getChat runs, it starts a Find of a set of objects, then it exits. The find is still running and response.success() has not yet been called, so the context is kept around. When the Find completes, the block is run. If the block then calls response.success(), the original call will be completed and the context deleted.